# Find digits in a list and concatenate all the items between the digits in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, slice

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
list1 = ['390140', 'string3', 'string2', '631019', 'string1', '', '6059152', 'string4', 'string5', '', '6951201', 'string6']
```

I have to convert this list into a list of dictionaries as below:

```
list2 = [{'code':'390140','description': 'string3 string2'}, {'code':'631019','description':'string1 '},{'code':'6051952','description': 'string4 string5', ...]
```

whereas each digit is a `code` and the following strings are the `description`. I have tried to the index of the digits and then slice the main list into sub-lists as shown in my approach below. This approach is not working.

```
#x = [item for item in list1 if item.isdigit()]

idx = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(list1) if item.isdigit()]

for i in idx:
    list2.append({'code': list1[i], 'description': ' '.join(list1[idx[i]:idx[i+1]])})
```

`list2` is the output I wish to obtain.

Comment: Please update your question with your evidence that your code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly with `itertools.groupby` function:

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = ['390140', 'string3', 'string2', '631019', 'string1', '', '6059152', 'string4', 'string5', '', '6951201', 'string6']
groups = groupby(list1, key=str.isdigit)
codes = [{'code': next(g), 'description': ' '.join(next(groups)[1])} for _, g in groups]
print(codes)
```

The output:

```
[{'code': '390140', 'description': 'string3 string2'},
 {'code': '631019', 'description': 'string1 '},
 {'code': '6059152', 'description': 'string4 string5 '},
 {'code': '6951201', 'description': 'string6'}]
```

Comment: While the other answers are also valid solutions, I am marking this as answer due to elegant, concise code.

Comment: @Roman very similar to what I was playing with posting...I was looking to handle some edge cases... so things like only starting accumulating when `str.isdigit` is true and then cater for when there's nothing following such a string to avoid an `IndexError` on `next`, eg: `codes = [{'code': next(g), 'description': ' '.join(next(groups, [[], []])[1])} for k, g in groups if k]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example: Loop over each element `el` in `list1`. If it is a digit, it is a code. Otherwise it is part of the description. Fill up `list2` with dicts `d` of this format, with `d['description']` initially being a list of the description `str`s. Once a new code begins, join all `str`s in the description `list` together.

```
list1 = ['390140', 'string3', 'string2', '631019', 'string1', '', '6059152', 'string4', 'string5', '', '6951201', 'string6']

list2 = []
d = None
for el in list1:
    if not el.isdigit():
        # This is (part of) the description
        if el:  # Only append non-empty elements
            d['description'].append(el)
        continue
    # Join elements of old description
    if d:  # Only do this if d exists
        d['description'] = ' '.join(d['description'])
    # Begin new dict
    d = {'code': el, 'description': []}
    list2.append(d)
# Join elements of the last description
d['description'] = ' '.join(d['description'])

print(list2)
```

Comment: Nice catch with the filtering of empty elements, i missed that in my answer

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to catch empty strings as part of the descriptions as the OP requires. (eg. `{'code':'631019','description':'string1 '}` )

Comment: @quamrana Oh. I did this deliberately as the other empty `str` is not used, as in `'string4', 'string5', ''` -> `'string4 string5'`. I guess OP should clarify how empty `str`s should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do to fix your code:

```
list1 = ['390140', 'string3', 'string2', '631019', 'string1', '', '6059152', 'string4', 'string5', '', '6951201', 'string6']

idxs = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(list1) if item.isdigit()]
idxs.append(len(list1))

list2 = []
for index, idx in enumerate(idxs[:-1]):
    code = list1[idx]
    desc = ' '.join(list1[idx + 1 : idxs[index + 1]])
    list2.append({'code': code, 'description': desc})

print(list2)
```

I append the length of the list onto the `idxs` array as a dummy, one beyond the end marker.

Then I enumerate through these indexes, except the dummy end one, to find the `code` directly from `list1` and the descriptions from the next item to one before the next `code`.

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools groupby to create groups, constructing string from groups and chunking into pairs to create dictionary (while writing it similar solution by RomanPerekhrest was posted, keeping it as slightly different):

```
from itertools import groupby
list1 = ['390140', 'string3', 'string2', '631019', 'string1', '', '6059152', 'string4', 'string5', '', '6951201', 'string6']
pairwise = [' '.join([*group]) for _, group in groupby(list1, key=str.isdigit)]
[{'code': c, 'description': d} for (c, d) in zip(*[iter(pairwise)] * 2)]
```